# Android WiFi Manager enableNetwork returns true but NetworkInfo state is always DISCONNECTED/SCANNING

Tags: android, rx-java2, wifimanager

I have written some code to enable a network with the given `networkId`, and to handle the asynchronous response via a `BroadcastReceiver`. However, even though `enableNetwork` returns true (indicating the OS successfully issue the command) my `BroadcastReceiver` never receives a `NetworkInfo` with `CONNECTED` state, it receives 2 events: `DISCONNECTED` and then `DISCONNECTED/SCANNING`.

From all the official docs and various SO questions I have read, if `enableNetwork` returns true then the `BroadcastReceiver` registered for handling `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` intents should always receive a `NetworkInfo` object with state `CONNECTED`.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Connects to the wifi access point at specified [ssid] with specified [networkId]
 * And returns the [WifiInfo] of the network that has been connected to
 */
private fun connect(context: Context,
                    wifiManager: WifiManager,
                    ssid: String,
                    networkId: Int) = Single.create<WifiInfo> { emitter ->

    val wifiConnectionReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        var oldSupplicantState: SupplicantState? = null

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) {
                val networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra<NetworkInfo>(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO) ?: return

                if (networkInfo.detailedState == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTED) {
                    context.applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(this)
                    emitter.onError(WiFiException("Failed to connect to wifi network"))
                }
                else if (networkInfo.detailedState == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
                    val wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra<WifiInfo>(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO) ?: return
                    if (ssid == wifiInfo.ssid.unescape()) {
                        context.applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(this)
                        emitter.onSuccess(wifiInfo)
                    }
                }
            } else if (intent.action == WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) {
                val supplicantState = intent.getParcelableExtra<SupplicantState>(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE)
                val oldSupplicantState = this.oldSupplicantState
                this.oldSupplicantState = supplicantState

                if (supplicantState == SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED) {
                    if (oldSupplicantState == null || oldSupplicantState == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
                        return
                    }
                    val possibleError = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR, -1)
                    if (possibleError == WifiManager.ERROR_AUTHENTICATING) {
                        context.applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(this)
                        emitter.onError(WiFiException("Wifi authentication failed"))
                    }
                } else if (supplicantState == SupplicantState.SCANNING && oldSupplicantState == SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED) {
                    context.applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(this)
                    emitter.onError(WiFiException("Failed to connect to wifi network"))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val networkStateChangedFilter = IntentFilter(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)
    networkStateChangedFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)

    context.applicationContext.registerReceiver(wifiConnectionReceiver, networkStateChangedFilter)

    emitter.setCancellable {
        if (!emitter.isDisposed)
            context.applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(wifiConnectionReceiver)
    }

    wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true)
}
```

Can anyone help? I'm really stumped. The `networkId` I am passing is valid as it has been created from `addNetwork` which is succeeding as it's not returning -1.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've finally figured this out and I hope that my answer here sheds some light for anyone in the future who encounters a similar problem, because this was nasty and caused me quite the headache.

The code in my question wasn't completely correct, but, it also wasn't the root cause of my problem. The root cause of the issue was that I had incorrectly configure the `WiFiConfig` object which was registered in the `WiFiConfig` table via `WiFiConfigManager.addNetwork()`.

I had made a massive assumption about the contract of `WifiConfigManager.addNetwork()`. I had assumed that if that operation succeeded (i.e. did NOT return `-1`) then the passed `WiFiConfig` was configured correctly. This assumption is incorrect, the `allowedAuthAlgorithms`, `allowedProtocols`, `allowedKeyManagers` and `allowedPairwiseCipher` `BitSet` on the `WiFiConfig` I was creating were incorrect, yet the call to `addNetwork()` succeeded. I believe this is because the call to `addNetwork()` does not actually do anything other than validate that the config *is valid to put in the `WiFiConfig` table*, which is quite different than validating if it *is the correct config for a given WiFi access point*. This is backed up by the comments in the source code for `addNetwork()` which do NOT state the delivery of asynchronous state like a lot of the other `WiFiManager` functions, indicating (to me at least) that no attempt to communicate with the access point was made by the OS as a result of calling `addNetwork()`.

Due to a very helpful suggestion by a colleague to connect to the access point in question via the OS, and then to compare the OS created `WiFiConfig` object for that access point with the one generated by my own code for discrepancies I noticed that my `WiFiConfig` was being configured incorrectly. It was shortly after this that I resolved the original question.

Now, why was my `WiFiConfig` object being created incorrectly? That is because I had little knowledge of how to configure WiFi (i.e. the various terminology and the meaning behind all the protocols, algorithms and key managers). So, after reading the official docs and not gleaning much helpful information I turned to StackOverflow questions and answers and found a recurring pattern for setting the `WiFiConfig` up correctly, they all appeared to use `BitWise` operators to create an `Int` value which was ultimately passed to the `WiFiConfig.allowedProtocols.set()`, `WiFiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set()`, `WiFiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set()` and `WiFiConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithm.set()` functions.

It turns out that the underlying `BitSet` for each of those configuration options is a data structure which maintains a dynamically resizing vector of bits, where the index of a bit in a given `BitSet` instance in the WiFiConfig object corresponded to the index of an element in a `String` array which was *implicitly* associated to the aforementioned `BitSet` within the WiFiConfig object. Therefore, if you wished to provide multiple `protocols`, `keyManagements`, `pairwiseCiphers` or `authAlgorithms` you would need to call `set` on the underlying `BitSet`, passing in the correct index which would correspond to the element of the String array which matched the chosen protocol.

After re-writing my `WiFiConfig` creation code, the issue resolved itself. Although there was a bug in my code in the original post which has also been fixed.

Here is the new WiFiConfig creation code:

```
/**
 * Emits a single of the [WifiConfiguration] created from the passed [scanResult] and [preSharedKey]
 */
private fun createWifiConfiguration(scanResult: WiFiScanResult, preSharedKey: String) = Single.fromCallable<WifiConfiguration> {
    val auth = scanResult.auth
    val keyManagement = scanResult.keyManagement
    val pairwiseCipher = scanResult.pairwiseCipher

    val config = WifiConfiguration()
    config.SSID = "\"" +  scanResult.ssid + "\""
    config.BSSID = scanResult.bssid

    if (auth.contains("WPA") || auth.contains("WPA2")) {
        config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA)
        config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN)
    }

    if (auth.contains("EAP"))
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.LEAP)
    else if (auth.contains("WPA") || auth.contains("WPA2"))
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN)
    else if (auth.contains("WEP"))
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED)

    if (keyManagement.contains("IEEE802.1X"))
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)
    else if (auth.contains("WPA") && keyManagement.contains("EAP"))
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
    else if (auth.contains("WPA") && keyManagement.contains("PSK"))
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK)
    else if (auth.contains("WPA2") && keyManagement.contains("PSK"))
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK)

    if (pairwiseCipher.contains("CCMP") || pairwiseCipher.contains("TKIP")) {
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)
    }

    if (preSharedKey.isNotEmpty()) {
        if (auth.contains("WEP")) {
            if (preSharedKey.matches("\\p{XDigit}+".toRegex())) {
                config.wepKeys[0] = preSharedKey
            } else {
                config.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + preSharedKey + "\""
            }
            config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0
        } else {
            config.preSharedKey = "\"" + preSharedKey + "\""
        }
    }

    config
}
```

And here is the new connect code:

```
/**
 * Connects to the wifi access point at specified [ssid] with specified [networkId]
 * And returns the [WifiInfo] of the network that has been connected to
 */
private fun connect(context: Context,
                    wifiManager: WifiManager,
                    ssid: String,
                    networkId: Int) = Single.create<WifiInfo> { emitter ->

    val wifiConnectionReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) {
                val networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra<NetworkInfo>(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO) ?: return

                if (networkInfo.detailedState == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
                    val wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra<WifiInfo>(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO) ?: return
                    if (ssid.unescape() == wifiInfo.ssid.unescape()) {
                        context.applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(this)
                        emitter.onSuccess(wifiInfo)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val networkStateChangedFilter = IntentFilter(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)
    networkStateChangedFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)

    context.applicationContext.registerReceiver(wifiConnectionReceiver, networkStateChangedFilter)

    emitter.setCancellable {
        if (!emitter.isDisposed)
            context.applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(wifiConnectionReceiver)
    }

    wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true)
}
```